# Docusign C# JWT Authentication Problem : Consent Required Exception

Tags: docusignapi

Currently doing a POC for one of our customer requirement. We will have a single admin user for the organization so JWT authentication suits our requirement. Since my developer account has not got admin feature enabled I cant grant administrative consent to my application, so we are blocked. Can you please give admin access to my account.
Just trying to follow through the steps in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAejcu-O1oE

Answer (score 1):

While Karan's recommendation to contact Support to have the Admin module enabled in your sandbox is accurate, I would also remind you that [Individual Consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/) is available for all account plans to grant permission to use JWT Auth